# Unable to load created virtual host in the browser

Tags: laravel, virtualhost, ubuntu-18.04

I want to create a virtual host for a laravel site. I followed the steps until `sudo a2ensite www.staysure-wb.local.conf` and it displays as the site is enabled. `Site www.staysure-wb.local already enabled`
But when I open the browser as **www.staysure-wb.local** it doesn't work.

I tried these commands after enabling site too. But it doesn't load in the browser.

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
sudo service apache2 reload
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Here is my **www.staysure-wb.local.conf** file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName staysure-wb.local 
        ServerAlias *.staysure-wb.local 
        DocumentRoot /home/mayuri/Documents/projects/staysure-wb/public
        <Directory /home/mayuri/Documents/projects/staysure-wb/public>
            AllowOverride All
            Require local
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.28:443>
        SSLEngine on
        ServerName staysure-wb.local 
    ServerAlias *.staysure-wb.local 
        DocumentRoot /home/mayuri/Documents/projects/staysure-wb/public 
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        #Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN


    <Directory /home/mayuri/Documents/projects/staysure-wb/public>
        php_admin_flag engine on
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteOptions Inherit 
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The site is available in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` as follows.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1240 Mar 26 10:02 www.staysure-wb.local.conf*
```

Here is the entry what I wrote in the hosts file:

```
126.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.28 www.staysure-wb.local

0.0.0.0 account.jetbrains.com
0.0.0.0 www.jetbrains.com
0.0.0.0 https://account.jetbrains.com:443
0.0.0.0 www-weighted.jetbrains.com
1.2.3.4 account.jetbrains.com
1.2.3.4 http://www.jetbrains.com
1.2.3.4 www-weighted.jetbrains.com
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
```

When I try to load **www.staysure-wb.local** in the browser url bar, it returns to Google search bar as follows. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSs9s.png)

Help me to load the site in the browser. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sharing a screenshot of the error message that's more helpful to answer.

Did you use vagrant? If yes, The following steps are helpful to you.

1. Add the content in /etc/apache2/sites-available/www.staysure-wb.local.conf

   **Make ensure the project folder path is correct or not**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/vagrant/locify/web"
ServerName locify.local
<Directory "/vagrant/locify/web">
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
AllowOverride All
Require all Granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

2. Enable the conf file

```
sudo a2ensite www.staysure-wb.local.conf
```

3. Enable rewrite module

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

4. Add the host entry in your local hosts file

```
<IP address> www.staysure-wb.local
```

Comment: When I try to load **www.staysure-wb.local** in the url bar, it returns to Google search bar. I attached the image to the question.  @Poonkodi

Comment: did you try with http://<your domain name>?  
**http://www.staysure-wb.local**